# TensorFlow seems not to use GPU

Tags: python, gpu, python-3.5, tensorflow

I use `TensorFlow` on Windows 8 and Python 3.5. I changed [this](https://tensorhub.com/donnemartin/4_multi_gpu) short example to see, if the GPU support (`Titan X)` works. Unfortunately the runtime with (`tf.device("/gpu:0"`) and without (`tf.device("/cpu:0"`)) using the GPU is the same. The Windows CPU monitoring shows that in both cases the CPU load is about 100% during the computation.

This is the code example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime

#num of multiplications to perform
n = 100

# Create random large matrix
matrix_size = 1e3
A = np.random.rand(matrix_size, matrix_size).astype('float32')
B = np.random.rand(matrix_size, matrix_size).astype('float32')

# Creates a graph to store results
c1 = []

# Define matrix power
def matpow(M, n):
    if n < 1: #Abstract cases where n < 1
        return M
    else:
        return tf.matmul(M, matpow(M, n-1))

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    a = tf.constant(A)
    b = tf.constant(B)
    #compute A^n and B^n and store results in c1
    c1.append(matpow(a, n))
    c1.append(matpow(b, n))

    sum = tf.add_n(c1)

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    # Runs the op.
    sess.run(sum)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()

print("computation time: " + str(t2-t1))
```

And here is the output for the GPU case:

```
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cublas64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cufft64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library curand64_80.dll locally
C:/Users/schlichting/.spyder-py3/temp.py:16: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  A = np.random.rand(matrix_size, matrix_size).astype('float32')
C:/Users/schlichting/.spyder-py3/temp.py:17: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  B = np.random.rand(matrix_size, matrix_size).astype('float32')
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX TITAN X
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.076
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 12.00GiB
Free memory: 2.40GiB
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
D c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:255] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0

Ievice mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0

C:0/task:0/gpu:0
host/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_108: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_109: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_110: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replicacalhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_107: (MatMul)/job:localgpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_103: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_104: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_105: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_106: (MatMul)/job:lo c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] Const_1: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_100: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_101: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul_102: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/Ionst_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0


MatMul_100: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul_101: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
...
MatMul_198: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul_199: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul_1: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul_2: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul_3: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
...
MatMul_98: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul_99: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
AddN: (AddN): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
computation time: 0:00:05.066000
```

In case of CPU the output is the same, with cpu:0 instead of `gpu:0`. The computation time doesn't change.
Even I use more operations, e.g. with a runtime of about 1 minute, the GPU and CPU is equal.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per log info, in particular device placement, your code *uses* GPU. Just the time to run is the same. My guess is that:

```
c1.append(matpow(a, n))
c1.append(matpow(b, n))
```

Is the bottleneck in your code, moving big matrices from GPU memory to RAM on and on. Can you try to:

- change the matrix size to `1e4 x 1e4`
- ```
  with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    A = tf.random_normal([matrix_size, matrix_size])
    B = tf.random_normal([matrix_size, matrix_size])
    C = tf.matmul(A, B)
  with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    sess.run(C)
    t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, the GPU is about 20x faster than the CPU.

Comment: Seems like for the matrix creation the tensorflow method, here tf.random_normal(), has to be used instead of defining a numpy matrix with np.random.rand().

Answer (score 2):

Say for instance creating the tensorflow session takes 4.9 seconds and the actual calculations only takes 0.1 on the cpu giving you a time of 5.0 seconds on the cpu.  Now say creating the session on the gpu also takes 4.9 seconds but the calculation takes 0.01 seconds giving a time of 4.91 seconds.  You would hardly see the difference. Creating the session is a one time overhead cost at the startup of a program.  You should not include that in your timing. Also tensorflow does some compilation/optimization when you call sess.run for the first time which makes the first run even slower.

Try timing it like this.

```
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    # Runs the op the first time.
    sess.run(sum)
    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(sum)
    t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
```

If this doesn't fix it it might also be that your calculation does not allow for enough parallelism for the GPU to really beat the cpu.  Increasing the matrix size might bring out the differences.